# Video.js Unable to pause video when SeekBar is clicked

Tags: javascript, video.js

Am trying to create a video where if a user clicks on the SeekBar it records the current time and also to pause the video on click event.

The issue is that when i click on the seekbar `player.pause()` is always undefined. How is it possible to include this in the below code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="player" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" data-setup="{}">
        <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.1.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.1.0/video.js"></script>


    <script>
        videojs('player').ready(function() {
            var player = this;
            player.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.on('mouseup', function(event) {
                var seekBarEl = this.el();
                var seekBarRect = videojs.dom.getBoundingClientRect(seekBarEl);
                var seekBarPoint = videojs.dom.getPointerPosition(seekBarEl, event).x;
                var duration = player.duration();
                var seekBarClickedTime = videojs.formatTime(seekBarPoint * duration, duration);
                console.log('Seekbar clicked time: ', seekBarClickedTime);
               player.pause();
              console.log(player.pause());
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[JSBIN Link](https://jsbin.com/tizoxotesa/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong about `undefined` when logging `player.pause()`. It simply means that `pause` method does not `return` anything. To make `.pause()` work you could invoke it from inside of the `setTimeout` function. Doing this will add your function to `event queue` and it will be invoked after `player`s original `mouseup` handler:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="player" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" data-setup="{}">
        <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.1.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.1.0/video.js"></script>


    <script>
        videojs('player').ready(function() {
            var player = this;
            player.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.on('mouseup', function(event) {
                var seekBarEl = this.el();
                var seekBarRect = videojs.dom.getBoundingClientRect(seekBarEl);
                var seekBarPoint = videojs.dom.getPointerPosition(seekBarEl, event).x;
                var duration = player.duration();
                var seekBarClickedTime = videojs.formatTime(seekBarPoint * duration, duration);
                console.log('Seekbar clicked time: ', seekBarClickedTime);

                setTimeout(() => player.pause(), 0);

                console.log(player.pause());
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And here's some simple example to get more understanding of what's going on:

```js
const elem1 = document.querySelector('.test1');
const elem2 = document.querySelector('.test2');

elem1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  elem1.classList.add('clicked')
})

elem1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  elem1.classList.remove('clicked')
})

elem2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(() => elem2.classList.add('clicked'), 0)
})

elem2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  elem2.classList.remove('clicked')
})
```

```css
.clicked {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button class="test1">test1</button>
<button class="test2">test2</button>
```

Comment: Can you point me to any reading material on why i need to use setTimeout for it to work?